# Xamarin iOS not using constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use Xamarin live to test my app on my iPhone, the issue is it doesn't seem to be using the constructor.

My `AppDelegate.cs` is

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
        string fileName = "books_db.sqlite";
        string fileLocation = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..", "Library");
        string full_path = Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App(full_path));

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Then in the main class I have 2 constructors `App()` and `App(string db_path)`; it is supposed to use the one with the parameter, but it uses the `App()` one.

Side question, am I using the right location to store users data, it is used to store a session token

**Edit:**

I make it use the default constructor that doesn't have parameters, but now it says

> Uncaught Exception Value cannot be null. Parameter name: image (ArugmentNullException)

The only thing that prints out is the [Debug Output](https://pastebin.com/xXCvHC9n)

Comment: By main class you mean the `Application` class right? also have you tried logging? as per your code it should hit proper constructor.

Comment: I tried change it to work without the constructor but now it says "Uncaught Exception Value cannot be null. Parameter name: image (ArugmentNullException)" and the output is https://pastebin.com/xXCvHC9n

Comment: @Fahadsk Edited post and added detail ^

Comment: @Fahadsk Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: please share your main class code, there is no information of error in your debug output.  also, should try to comment code from the point where you've successfully run your project, its likely that this issue is because of some plugin you have installed recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the built-in [Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) dictionary to store the session token.

```
Application.Current.Properties ["token"] = session;
```

I wouldn't suggest you pass the path of the location to the `App.cs` of the PCL/Shared project, it won't work on an eventual Android project.

Comment: I updated the PCL to use the Property and it works great on android but with Xamarin Live I get a notifications for "Uncaught Exception Value cannot be null. Parameter name: image (ArugmentNullException)

Comment: I think that's something different, could you post a stack trace?

Comment: This is all it prints out since it's on the Xamarin live player. https://pastebin.com/xXCvHC9n